# String Comparison ignoring special characters C#

Tags: string, comparison, special-characters

I am creating a generic List if unique strings.My string formats are like GBP/101-P506 some time it could be GBP-101-P-506. Both of these strings have to be considered as SAME. how could I compare such strings?

Answer (score 0):

Most straight forward way would be, to replace the special characters with empty strings and compare the results...
Use temporary variables if you don't want to modify your originals.

Regards

Comment: It is better to replace all special characters by one special character (not empty space) to avoid mixing of ("GBR/12/3" and "GBR-1-23").

Answer (score 0):

RegEx the input and normalize the data before entering it into your data structure. If you don't want to change the original strings, you will have to consider all possible valid values anytime you need to perform operations on the strings.